# Jupyter notebook inline plotting breaks, when loading matplotlib rcparams from matplotlibrc file

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I want to write a module with a function to set default style parameters from a `matplotlibrc` file. A minimal example of the module `style.py`:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

def set_default():
    mpl.rc_file('./matplotlibrc')
```

If I want to use the module in a jupyter notebook with inline plotting, the inline plot is not shown, when I call `style.set_default()` before having plotted anything before.

So If I call

```
%matplotlib inline
style.set_default()
plt.plot()
```

the output is an empty list and no plot is shown. If I call e.g.

```
plt.plot()
```

after enabling inline plotting and before calling the `set_default` function, the output of both `plot` calls is shown inline.

This even happens, when the `matplotlibrc` file is empty as it is in my minimal example.

Does anyone understand why this happens and has an idea how to solve this problem or another way how to set a default style in a module using a `matplotlibrc` file?

Here are also two images of both cases in a jupyter notebook:

[inline broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RzrK.png)

[inline working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkNad.png)

Extra question: Why is the second plot in the second case larger, when the loaded `matplotlibrc` is empty?

Comment: First of all, can you try with the `%matplotlib inline` line the very first (before any import) line of your notebook?

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short version: Use `mpl.style.use` instead of `mpl.rc_file`.

Long version:
You may print out the backend in use to see what is going on.

```
import matplotlib as mpl

def set_default():
    mpl.rc_file('matplotlibrc.txt') # this is an empty file

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print mpl.get_backend()
# This prints u'TkAgg' (in my case) the default backend in use 
#  due to my rc Params

%matplotlib inline
print mpl.get_backend()
# This prints "module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline", because inline has been set
set_default()
print mpl.get_backend()
# This prints "agg", because this is the default backend reset by setting the empty rc file
plt.plot()
# Here, no plot is shown because agg (a non interactive backend) is used.
```

Until here no supprise.

Now the second case.

```
import matplotlib as mpl

def set_default():
    mpl.rc_file('matplotlibrc.txt') # this is an empty file

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print mpl.get_backend()
# This prints u'TkAgg' (in my case) the default backend in use, same as above

%matplotlib inline
print mpl.get_backend()
# This prints "module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline", because inline has been set
plt.plot()
# This shows the inline plot, because the inline backend is active.

set_default()
print mpl.get_backend()
# This prints "agg", because this is the default backend reset by setting the new empty rc file
plt.plot()
# Here comes the supprise: Although "agg" is the backend, still, an inline plot is shown.
# This is due to the inline backend being the one registered in pyplot 
#   when doing the first plot. It cannot be changed afterwards.
```

The main point is, you may still change the backend, until the first plot is produced, not after.

The same argument goes for the figure size. The default matplotlib figure size is `(6.4,4.8)`, while the one being set with the inline backend is `(6.0,4.0)`. Also the figure dpi is different, it is `100` in the default rcParams, but `72.` in the inline configuration. This makes the plot appear much smaller.

Now to the actual problem. I suppose the use of a stylesheet is meant here to set some styles for plots, not to change the backend. Hence you would rather only set the style from the rc file. This can be done in the usual way,using `matplotlib.style.use`

```
def set_default():
    mpl.style.use('matplotlibrc.txt')
```

When this is used, it will not overwrite the backend in use, but only **update** those parameters, specified in the file itself.

Comment: Many thanks for the careful explanation! It works perfectly using `mpl.style.use` and I think I now do understand what happened :)

Comment: Thank so much. I was starting to lose my mind over this. In some jupyter notebook cells, I call a script that changes global styles, which itself calls `rcdefaults`, which breaks inline plotting if it's called before a figure is drawn. It seemed like inline plotting arbitrarily failed depending on which cell I picked at the start of my session.

Comment: @LukeDavis exactly my problem too. Although I used seaborn and the plots worked, if you imported seaborn _before_ (really) running rcdefaults. WTF